# UnsupportedOperationException GlassFish error

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, glassfish

I'm using JSF2 and JPA Eclipse Link on Glassfish 3.1.

I developed an application in a local environment and I have no issues there. Now I'm trying to deploy it on a public server but I ended up with some weird behaviour.

When trying to deploy the application I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

and the stack trace looks like this:

```
Critical error during deployment: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) at     java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355) 
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:256)
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:255)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4690)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:534)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5305)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDe    ploymentFacility.java:143)
org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420) 
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394) 
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150) 
at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98) 
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88) 
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769) 
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300) 
at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166) 
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) 
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) 
at     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) 
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) 
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) 
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) 
at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600) 
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96) 
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225) 
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) 
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) 
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) 
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) 
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) 
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) 
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) 
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [Maze] failed. Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7333] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: The reference column name [id] mapped on the element [field country] does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference. 
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:126) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:105) 
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source) 
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source) 
at com.maze.factory.EMFactory.initComplete(EMFactory.java:30) 
at com.maze.factory.EMFactory.getInstance(EMFactory.java:23) 
at com.maze.service.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:12) 
at com.maze.service.CountryService.<init>(CountryService.java:14) 
at com.maze.service.factory.ServiceFactory.getCountryService(ServiceFactory.java:47) 
at com.maze.util.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:175) ... 88 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [Maze] failed. Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7333] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: The reference column name [id] mapped on the element [field country] does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference. 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1127) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:101) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:96) ... 96 more Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [Maze] failed. Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7333] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: The reference column name [id] mapped on the element [field country] does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference. 
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:210) ... 99 more Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7333] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: The reference column name [id] mapped on the element [field country] does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference. 
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidReferenceColumnName(ValidationException.java:1793) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.MetadataAccessor.getReferencedField(MetadataAccessor.java:437) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.MetadataAccessor.getReferencedField(MetadataAccessor.java:386) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processOneToOneForeignKeyRelationship(MappingAccessor.java:1574) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOneToOneForeignKeyRelationship(ObjectAccessor.java:614) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOwningMappingKeys(ObjectAccessor.java:667) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToOneAccessor.process(ManyToOneAccessor.java:110) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1350) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1572) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:486) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:454) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1081) ... 98 more
```

** The reference column name [id] mapped on the element [field country] does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference. **

Now am I to understand that a mapping involving a Country entity and an Id field are involved somehow? Relying this I removed all JPA mappings involving the Country entity but I still get this error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a wild guess. do you already have the table which you want to create or insert values through jpa.

it looks like the table schema and database and your java application do not match.